# How to properly check API null response in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http

```
Future<List<AlbumList>> _getRecentUpdates() async{
     String? schoolId = await SharedPreferencesHelper().getSchoolId();
     final url = "${ErpGlobal.getBaseUrl()}${ErpGlobal.albumList}$schoolId";
     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: Utils.header);
     if(response.statusCode == 200){
      if(response.body != null){
        debugPrint("Nul response");
        return [];
      }
      final List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return body.map((json) => AlbumList.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }
    else{
    return [];
    }
  }
```

I was learning API calls in flutter and I found an issue with VS code. When I save the code and run the app it automatically removed null check condition. Can you please tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if(response.body != null){
```

needs to be

```
if(response.body == null){
```

if you really wanted to check for `null`. But the thing is also that `response.body` is guaranteed to never be `null` so you probably actually want to check for

```
if(response.body.isEmpty){
```